# CSS Animation bugs in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, haml

I am trying to spin 2 cards, one an icon and other a value
My haml snippet for it is

```
.card
        .side.back
          %span.txt {{ notifications.length }}
        .side
          %i.material-icons.small_icon remove_red_eye
```

This works perfectly fine in chrome/chromium and opera, but in mozilla firefox, the eye icon appears along with the data value. My CSS snippet for mozilla compatibility is

```
.card{
-moz-animation-name: spin;
-moz-animation-duration: 2500ms;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin{
        from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg); }
        to { -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    }
```

What can I do to fix it?

```css
.card .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: none;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.card .back {
  font-size: x-small!important;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  animation: spin 2500ms linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
.small_icon {
  font-size: x-small!important;
}
.badge1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="badge1">
  <div class="card-container badge1"></div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="side back">
      <span class="txt">10</span>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
      <i class="material-icons small_icon">remove_red_eye</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first, remove these vendor prefixes, or at least make sure they are set before the non-prefixed ones. `animation-` and `transform` properties are non-prefixed since a very long time, and you can't be sure the prefixed versions will be up-to-date.

Comment: @Kaiido tried it, didn't work

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE] with the computed values that does reproduce the issue?

Comment: ```.card {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1.5s;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2500ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2500ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  }```
The snippet for css card property @Kaiido

Comment: @Kaiido here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xdjotxft/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this :

```css
.card{
-moz-animation-name: spin;
animation-duration: 2500ms;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes spin{
        from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
        to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    }
```

```html
          <div class="card">
            <div class="side back">
             <span>sdjfkdsjkfj</span>
            </div>
            <div class="side back">
             <i class="icon">hh</i>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is something quite weird here, and I unfortunately don't know exactly what, nor whose implementation is correct.

But what Firefox doesn't like is that your front element doesn't have its own `transform` outside of the animation.

Somehow, this seems to make `transform-style: preserve-3d` lost.

So two workarounds:

- Set an initial `transform: rotateY(0);`.

  ```css
  .card .side {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border: none;
    background: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* makes FF happy */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  .card .back {
    font-size: x-small!important;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .card {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    animation: spin 2500ms linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
  }
  .small_icon {
    font-size: x-small!important;
  }
  .badge1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="badge1">
    <div class="card-container badge1"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="side back">
        <span class="txt">10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <i class="material-icons small_icon">remove_red_eye</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

  - Set `transform-style: preserve-3d` again on your inner elements

  ```css
  .card .side {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border: none;
    background: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* makes FF happy */
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  .card .back {
    font-size: x-small!important;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  .card {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    animation: spin 2500ms linear infinite;
  }

  @keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
  }
  .small_icon {
    font-size: x-small!important;
  }
  .badge1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 100px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="badge1">
    <div class="card-container badge1"></div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="side back">
        <span class="txt">10</span>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <i class="material-icons small_icon">remove_red_eye</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```